# beautifulsoup not parsing html correctly

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td></tr><tr>  <td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr> <tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr></table>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print soup.getText()
```

But the output is empty, yet with other html samples it works just fine.
The html is like that because it is extracted from a table.

```
html = '<p>Content</p></td></table>'
```

That works just fine for example. Any help?

Edit: I know the HTML is not valid, but the second HTML sample is also invalid yet that works.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `lxml` is having trouble parsing invalid `HTML`.

Use `html.parser` instead of `lxml`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td></tr><tr>  <td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr> <tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr></table>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print soup.getText()
```

Output:

```
 Data I want      Data I want       Data I want
```

Answer (score 2):

if the consistent issue is missing the opening tag you can use regular expression to find what it should be like the below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td></tr><tr>  <td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr> <tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr></table>'
pat = re.compile('</[a-z]*>')
L = list(re.findall(pat, html))
if L[0] != L[len(L)-1]:
    html = L[len(L)-1].replace('/','') + html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print soup.getText()
```

output is

```
Data I want      Data I want       Data I want
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not a valid HTML. Why don't you change it to the following?

```
html = '<table><tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td></tr><tr>  <td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr> <tr><td colspan="3">   Data I want  </td> </tr></table>'
```

But there is probably something missing before the sample you posted. Where does the HTML code come from?

Comment: I know it is not valid HTML, its because I am extracting it from a large source file. But the second example I gave is also invalid HTML, yet is parsed just fine and outputs the contents

Comment: I guess beautifulsoup just handles some invalid HTML but not all. It seems that it's not a problem to have non-sensual tags in the end of the string but it is a problem if it starts with them. I don't know why extracting it from a large file should explain or excuse the HTML's invalidity. It seems that you should extract it better. Do you need any help with it?